# Расширенный поиск

Tags: php, mysql, email, search

Друзья реализовал поиск - но сделал пока только по одному полю!
Подскажите как правильно запрос составить!
Вот форма:

```
<form method="post" action="№" class="box">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Марка</p> 
                        <select name="marka" style="width: 300px;">
                            {source 0}<?php 
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM pnc0g_listbingo_ads";  
                                $res = mysql_query($query); 
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {  
                                    $jsondata = $row['extrafield_values'];  
                                     $data = json_decode($jsondata, true); 
                                     echo ("<option value='".$data['marka']."'>".$data['marka']."</option>");
                                } 
                            ?>  
                            {/source}                               
                        </select>
                        <p>Город</p>
                        <select name="regionid" style="width: 300px;">
                            {source 0}
                            <?php   
                                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM pnc0g_listbingo_regions";
                                $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

                                while  ( ($regions = mysql_fetch_array($result2)))
                                {
                                    echo ("<option value='".$regions['listbingo_region_id']."'>".$regions['title']."</option>");
                                } 

                            ?>      
                            {/source}
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Модель</p>
                        <input type="text" id="model" name="model" value="" style="width: 300px;">  
                        <p>Предложение за</p>  
                        <select name="pridloj" style="width: 300px;">
                            <option value="1day">1 день</option>
                            <option value="2day">2 дня</option>
                            <option value="3day">3 дня</option>
                            <option value="7day">7 дней</option>
                            <option value="month">месяц</option> 
                        </select>               
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Год</p>  
                        <select name="god" style="width: 100px;">
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                            <option value="2011">2011</option>
                            <option value="2010">2010</option>
                            <option value="2009">2009</option>
                            <option value="2008">2008</option>
                            <option value="2007">2007</option>
                            <option value="2006">2006</option>
                            <option value="2005">2005</option>
                            <option value="2004">2004</option>
                            <option value="2003">2003</option>
                            <option value="2002">2002</option>
                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                            <option value="1999">1999</option>
                            <option value="1998">1998</option>
                            <option value="1997">1997</option>
                            <option value="1996">1996</option>
                            <option value="1995">1995</option>
                            <option value="1994">1994</option>
                            <option value="1993">1993</option>
                            <option value="1992">1992</option>
                            <option value="1991">1991</option>
                            <option value="1990">1990</option>
                            <option value="1989">1989</option>
                            <option value="1988">1988</option>
                            <option value="1987">1987</option>
                            <option value="1986">1986</option>
                            <option value="1985">1985</option>
                            <option value="1984">1984</option>
                            <option value="1983">1983</option>
                            <option value="1982">1982</option>
                            <option value="1981">1981</option>
                            <option value="1980">1980</option>
                        </select> - 
                        <select name="god_do" style="width: 100px;">
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                            <option value="2011">2011</option>
                            <option value="2010">2010</option>
                            <option value="2009">2009</option>
                            <option value="2008">2008</option>
                            <option value="2007">2007</option>
                            <option value="2006">2006</option>
                            <option value="2005">2005</option>
                            <option value="2004">2004</option>
                            <option value="2003">2003</option>
                            <option value="2002">2002</option>
                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                            <option value="1999">1999</option>
                            <option value="1998">1998</option>
                            <option value="1997">1997</option>
                            <option value="1996">1996</option>
                            <option value="1995">1995</option>
                            <option value="1994">1994</option>
                            <option value="1993">1993</option>
                            <option value="1992">1992</option>
                            <option value="1991">1991</option>
                            <option value="1990">1990</option>
                            <option value="1989">1989</option>
                            <option value="1988">1988</option>
                            <option value="1987">1987</option>
                            <option value="1986">1986</option>
                            <option value="1985">1985</option>
                            <option value="1984">1984</option>
                            <option value="1983">1983</option>
                            <option value="1982">1982</option>
                            <option value="1981">1981</option>
                            <option value="1980">1980</option>
                        </select>
                        <p>Цена</p>
                        <input type="text" id="price_from" name="price_from" value="" style="width: 85px;"> - 
                        <input type="text" id="price_to" name="price_to" value="" style="width: 85px;">             
                    </td>
                    </tr>
```

Вот обработчик:

```html
<?php 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'ads_word');
define('DB_PASS', 'ads_word');
define('DB_NAME', 'ads_word');

if (!mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS)) {
    exit('Cannot connect to server');
}
if (!mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)) {
    exit('Cannot select database');
}

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

function search ($query) 
{ 
    $query = trim($query); 
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

    if (!empty($query)) 
    { 
        if (strlen($query) < 3) {
            $text = '<p>Слишком короткий поисковый запрос.</p>';
        } else if (strlen($query) > 128) {
            $text = '<p>Слишком длинный поисковый запрос.</p>';
        } else { 
            $q = "SELECT `title` FROM `pnc0g_listbingo_ads` WHERE `title` LIKE '%$query%'";

            $result = mysql_query($q);

            if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
                $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

                $text = '<p>По запросу <b>'.$query.'</b> найдено совпадений: '.$num.'</p>';

                do {
                    // Делаем запрос, получающий ссылки на статьи
                    $q1 = "SELECT * FROM `pnc0g_listbingo_ads` WHERE `title` = '$row[title]'";
                    $result1 = mysql_query($q1);

                    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                        $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
                    }

                    $text .= '<p>'.$row['title'].'</p>';

                } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); 
            } else {
                $text = '<p>По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.</p>';
            }
        } 
    } else {
        $text = '<p>Задан пустой поисковый запрос.</p>';
    }

    return $text; 
} 
?>

<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['marka'])) { 
    $search_result = search ($_POST['marka']); 
    echo $search_result; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Ох сейчас как набегут люди, кричащие что расширение mysql устарело и надо срочно использовать mysqli или PDO

Comment: А что сейчс не работает? (кроме того что вы забыли экранировать проценты в запросах, или это так задумано?)

Comment: Это конечно хорошо!
Но мне нужно хотя бы с этим разобраться

Comment: сейчас работает - но по 1 полю - марка, а нужно что бы проверя ло все поля

Comment: Воспользуйтесь операцией `OR` в `WHERE`, например `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE title LIKE '%word%' OR description LIKE '%word%'`

Comment: это для полей типа select, и input text, а если как проверить type="checkbox" и например если есть год от и до - как вывести диапазон

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24101/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and-lxxnutsxxl).